# (PHP MYSQL) Dividir intervalo de horas em quantidade de usuários e salvar no mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia, amigos programadores. Gostaria de um auxílio, tenho um banco em mysql com certa quantidade de usuários, e preciso pegar o intervalo de horas (ex: 10:00 até 14:00) e dividir pela quantidade de usuários, e em seguida definir o valor dividido para cada usuário. Ou seja, vamos supor que eu tenha 4 usuários, aí divide o intervalo de horas e dará uma hora para cada. Aí preciso que esse resultado da divisão seja inserido para os usuários.

Ex: Divide o intervalo (10:00 às 14:00), e atribui para cada usuário.

user1 = 10:00 às 10:59:59

user2 = 11:00 às 11:59:59

user3 = 12:00 às 12:59:59

user4 = 13:00 às 14:00:00

Comment: Para que possamos ajudar, dê algum exemplo mais concreto, por exemplo a estrutura dessa tabela onde armazena esses dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos lá, para dividir você precisa da hora inicial e final, esta sempre sendo uma maior que a outra.

```
   <?php

     $hora_inicial = strtotime("10:00:00");
     $hora_final = strtotime("14:00:00");

     $intervalo = abs($string2 - $string1);
     //Agora que temos o intervalo vamos verificar quantos usuários existem no banco

     $mysqli = new mysqli("host","user","password","db");

     $count = 0;
     if($sth = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM suatabela")){
         while ($row = $sth->fetch_assoc()) {
            $count++;
         }
     }

     //Agora o count tem a quantidade de usuários, então pegamos o intervalo e dividimos pela quantidade.
     $intervalo = ($intervalo/$count);

    //Agora mandamos para o banco:
    //Utilziae insert ou update, depende da sua lógica aí
    if($mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM suatbela"){
          while ($row = $sth->fetch_assoc()) {
          //pego o id do usuário atual.
          $id = $row['id'];

          //Converter os segundos em horas
          $hora_inicial2 = gmdate("H:i:s", $hora_inicial);

          //Hora final é a hora inicial + o intervalo
          $hora_final2 = gmdate("H:i:s", $hora_inicial+$intervalo);

          //Então você seta a nova hora inicial para a ultima final para que no próximo loop a seja uma nova hora inicial
          $hora_inicial = strtotime("$horafinal2");

          //E faço o update em seu id no campo do intervalo
          $mysqli->query("UPDATE suatabela SET intervalo = '$hora_inicial2 às $hora_final2' WHERE id='$id'");
          }
    }
```

Comment: @ProgramadorLunático o que eu fiz aí foi só um exemplo simples, man, daí se te ajudar você aplica sua lógica e conclui, porque você não colocou nada do seu código, não dá para saber o que você está fazendo

Comment: Não pow, não deu para escrever tudo, meu filho apertou aqui e não consigo editar a resposta kkkkkkk, eu ia mandar isso.

Comment: Cara, comecei a fazer algo parecido, mas está bem mais elaborado o seu.
A ideia do que pretendo fazer, é um sistema de consultório.
Então, tenho os pacientes e os horários que eles informam que podem ir ao consultório, tipo, paciente1 pode ir entre às 08:00 e 10:00 no consultório, não pode passar desse horário.
Porém o consultório fica aberto das 08:00 até às 19:00.
Aí tenho que adequar os horários para cada paciente, dentro do horário de atendimento do consultorio mas respeitando o horário que o cliente pode ir.
Loucura né? kkkkk
Por isso que estou quebrando a cabeça kkkkkk

Comment: Ahhhhh tá, então você tem as horas definidas e ao ir lançando não quer que passe do horário máximo, certo?

Comment: Pela sua pergunta eu entendi que você fosse lançar um horário final e inicial e todos os clientes cadastrados pegassem esse intervalo dividido pelo total e separasse a mesma quantidade para todos

Comment: Exatamente. 
Tenho os cliente no banco, e cada um tem uma limitação de hora.
Tipo, paciente1 só pode ir das 08:00 às 10:00, depois desse horário, ele não consegue.
E o expediente do consultório é das 08:00 às 19:00.
Então, preciso dividir o intervalo das 08:00 às 19:00 pela quantidade de pacientes que tenho, e o valor dividido, ir inserindo para cada paciente, desde que esteja dentro do horário que ele pode ir.

user1 = 10:00 às 10:59:59
user2 = 11:00 às 11:59:59
user3 = 12:00 às 12:59:59
user4 = 13:00 às 14:00:00

Comment: @ProgramadorLunático ah então meu exemplo cabe perfeitamente, caso tenha algum erro de sintaxe eu peço perdão kkkkkk, fiz direto daqui, então posso acabar digitando algo errado, mas como cada dia você deve trocar os horários, você deve também adicionar o campo do dia, se não vai dividir para todos os clientes de todos os tempos

Comment: Não cara, ficou show o seu exemplo, estou adequando as ideias aqui.
Vou tentar resolver o problema, e te falo.

Comment: @ProgramadorLunático blz kkkk, se resolver seu problema aí e você quiser marcar minha resposta como aceita eu agradeço também kkkkkk

Comment: Demorei para responder, mas deu tudo certinho.
Vlw parceiro!